# Помогите с кодом FlexBox

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что-бы они шли ровно в ряд

html

```
        <title>
            Name
        </title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=6dff0ea5ac1716a1fc0775f15f5ca7f3">
            </div>

            <p id="Text">
                NameStudio
            </p>

            <div id="podtext">

            </div>

            <div id="strelka">

            </div>
        </div>
```

css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700');

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

## header{

```
height: 850px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #1E1E2A;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: row;
```

}

## logo{

```
margin-top: 50px;
```

}

## Text{

```
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font: bold;
font-size: 80px;
color: white;
margin-top: 600px;
display: block;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Трэш какой-то вы наваяли. И вопрос хорошо бы задать по-человечески.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #1E1E2A;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <p id="text">NameStudio</p>
  <div id="podtext"></div>
  <div id="strelka"></div>
</div>
```